# C++ reading input from char* argv[]

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm just learning C++ and am trying to write a program that will take in inputs from `char* argv[]` and process them.

Each `argv[]` will be 6 hexadecimal, e.g. `1A2B3C`

I have a `char` array
- `char message[3]`

and I'm trying to put `1A` into `message[0]`, `2B` into `message[1]`, and `3C` into `message[2]`.

I understand `argv` is kind of like a 2D array, so if my command line is:

> ./test 2 1A2B3C 4D5E6F

`argv[2][0]` would give me '1' and `argv[2][1]` would give me 'A'

but I don't know how to read 2 `char` together and put them into the `char` array.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: look up some basic tutorials on the internet. there should be a lot how to read command line arguments.

Comment: For the moment, forget about `argv`. Start with `const char input[] = "1A2B3C";` and write some code that tries to do what you're looking for. If you have trouble, post that code. Once you get that working, you can deal with the added intricacies of `argv`.

Comment: Advise: use `std::string` it will really simplify your code ;)

Comment: char* argv[] and char** are a bit difficult for some to get their mind around when starting out.  What it is is an array of words (strings).  So rather than answer directly you need to make some design decisions on what data type you want to stuff each string into (e.g stl::string, char*, or other representation).  The argv[] also has connotations that you will be using argc to perform some validation/safety checks on whether the data exists before diving into the handling.

Answer (score 9):

If the main function is declared like this

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
```

Calling

./test 1A2B3C 4D5E6F

will result in an argv array which looks similiar to

[image]

- **argc** is the number of entries in argv
- **argv** is an array of strings (actual a [Pointer to the first element of an array of pointers to null-terminated multibyte strings](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/main_function))

In argv

- the first entry is always the path and executable name, e.g. "/home/user/test" (the picture only shows test to keep things simple)
- the remaining entries are the command line arguments ("1A2B3C" and "4D5E6F" in this case).
- each entry in argv is in turn a character array

So for the example

- argv[1] = ['1','A','2','B','3','C','\0']

To extract sub-strings from the arguments

- Convert each argument to a string (std::string s(argv[1]) It's easier to work with strings than with char*
- Extract sub strings (s.substr(0,2))
- Convert each sub string to an integer ([strtol(substring,NULL,16)](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/strtol/))

Try this example code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h> //required for string to int conversion

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

  std::cout << "executable= " << argv[0] << std::endl;

  for (int i=1; i<argc; i++) {
    std::string s(argv[i]); //put char array into a string

    std::cout << "arg["<<i<<"]="<<s<<std::endl;

    for (int j=0; j<6; j+=2) {

      std::string byteString = s.substr(j, 2);

      char byte = (char) strtol(byteString.c_str(), NULL, 16);

      std::cout << "byteString= "<<byteString << " as integer= "<<(int)byte<<std::endl;
    }
  }
}
```

Calling  "./test 1A2B3C 4D5E6F" outputs

```
executable= /home/user/test
arg[1]=1A2B3C
byteString= 1A as integer= 26
byteString= 2B as integer= 43
byteString= 3C as integer= 60
arg[2]=4D5E6F
byteString= 4D as integer= 77
byteString= 5E as integer= 94
byteString= 6F as integer= 111
```

---

Alternatively, if the command line arguments could already be split, i.e.

```
"./test 1A 2B 3C 4D 5E 6F"
```

The substring extraction can be avoided.